# Red Symbol on Server Roles

Tags: sql-server

I was RDP to one of my servers (SQL Server 2012 (SP4) Std Ed) and saw that the Server Roles had a red symbol (not a red x), but when I connect to that server through a VPN using MSSQL that red symbol doesn't show.  I have been through MS knowledgebases and no explanation what so ever. Anybody knows what it means and how to remove this?
[image]

Comment: In my case, I have no principal disabled, in this image you can see that there is only one user disabled.

Comment: The "principal disabled" is the red arrow not the red pin. It has no connection. This is just bonus information about red things provided in the linked thread...

Answer (score 2):

Zooming in on the icon it looks like a red push pin.

[image]

Searching specifically for red pin and management studio I found [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cd3dd230-a17c-4feb-89bc-1a3e4f4c7fe6/sql-server-roles-are-disabled?forum=sqlservermigration) which explains

> If a principal is disabled, then it has a red arrow pointing down in
> the icon ... Here you have a red pin icon and
> this means you can't modify it. Since SQL Server 2014 we can create
> user defined server role ... which
> wasn't possible in SQL Server 2012 and lower version ... user defined
> roles don't have a red pin and can be modified, while predefined
> server roles do have a pin

One exception is that the permissions of the `public` role can be altered (but membership can't). For all other pre-defined server roles the reverse is true.

In more recent versions of management studio it appears a lock icon is used for that instead.

[image]

Comment: I believe you have a point there, the SSMS Vers. is 11.0 (showing the red pin) and the one that I have is 18.5 it shows the locks like the ones on your image.